# How can I display different values on xAxes than on tooltip Chart.js V3

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I am not really familiar with the Chart.js V3.7.0(This is the version I am currently using) So I tried in different ways to display different values on xAxes and different values on the tooltip.
What's important here to note, is that I am using `Php` to `echo` the values inside the dataset.

**For example** *(the `data` variable I use)*:

```
      const data = {
        datasets: [{
          backgroundColor: 'black',
          borderColor: '#2d84b4',
          borderWidth: 2,
           fill: false,
            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            pointHoverBackgroundWidth: 5,
            pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(45, 132, 180, 0.5)',
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 4,
            pointStyle: 'circle',
            pointHoverRadius: 5.5,
            data: [ <? echo $values; ?> ],
        }], 
            labels: [ <? echo $labels; ?> ],
      };
```

So my `php` echoes the `$values` variable with values in this form: 
`{0.504, 0.675, 0.305, etc...}`

Same applies for the `$labels` variable but because `labels` are data related to time I display them as strings: 
*example*: `{'Dec 28', '01:00', '02:00', etc...}`

**Here** is the `config` variable which includes the `data` variable inside of it, and then the `config` variable is being called inside the initialization of the chart.

**Config**:

```
const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        onHover: (event, activeElements) => {
            if (activeElements?.length > 0) {
              event.native.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            } else {
              event.native.target.style.cursor = 'auto';
            }
          },
        animation: {
            duration: 0
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            x: {
                stacked : true,
                ticks: {
                    autoSkip: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: <? echo $ticks_val; ?>,
                    maxRotation: 0
                },
                grid: {
                  display: true,
                  drawBorder: false,
                  drawOnChartArea: false,
                  drawTicks: true,
                  tickLength: 3,
                },
            },
            yAxes: {
                    min: '0.0',
                    ticks: {
                        autoSkip: true,
                        maxTicksLimit: 6,
                    },
                    grid: {
                        drawBorder: false,
                        drawTicks: false
                    }
                },
            },
            elements: {
                point: {
                    radius: 5
                }
            },
            locale: 'en-EN',
            plugins: {
              tooltip: {
                displayColors: false,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(45,132,180,0.8)',
                bodyFontColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                callbacks: {
                  title: () => {
                    return
                  },
                  label: (ttItem) => ( `${ttItem.parsed.y} ppm` ),
                  afterBody: (ttItems) => (ttItems[0].label)
                }
              },
              legend: {
                display: false
              }
            }
          }  
        };
```

**Goal**:
I want to `echo` a different `php` variable inside the `tooltip`, but I dont want to change what I am currently displaying on `xAxes`. Problem is that If I just echo another `php` variable in the tooltip, I end up with the wrong Date date being displayed simply because the index values are not connected with the chart and so on with the tooltip popup.

**Notes**:

1): Chart.js version: 3.7.0

**Picture** of the *chart*:

[image]

Comment: I cannot follow the "goal" part of your question clearly enough. What exactly do you want to display in the `tooltip`?

Comment: I want to display a different value in the Tooltip than what the xAxes value is, but I want to keep the relationship of the xAxes and the yAxes inside of the new value I will display, For example in the chart I want xAxes to display data like the picture shows but in the tooltip  I want to display the data the xAxes has in chart + the Date for example: if xAxes in chart has 17:00 as value then I want the tooltip to not display only 17:00 but `Dec 26 17:00` (as shown in the picture's tooltip and chart).

Comment: Can you amend the data stored at `$labels`, so that the values are in the format you want displayed in the tooltip, i.e. change `$labels` to `{'Dec 28', 'Dec 28 01:00', 'Dec 28 02:00' .....}`? If so, we can use a callback to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is achievable. One solution would be to reformat the values stored at `$labels` so that they are consistent. For example, store each value in the format that you want to render, i.e. `{'Dec 28 00:00', 'Dec 28 01:00', 'Dec 02:00'}`. You can then use a callback to create a custom tick format.

```
options: {
    scales: {
        x: {
            stacked : true,
            ticks: {
                autoSkip: true,
                maxTicksLimit: 12,
                maxRotation: 0,
                callback: function(value) {
                    let labelValue = this.getLabelForValue(value);
                    if(labelValue.slice(-5, -3) == '00') {
                        return labelValue.slice(0, -6);
                    } else {
                        return labelValue.slice(-5);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle showing this working](https://jsfiddle.net/643ag9c2/)